How do I evaluate a specific recipe and a wildcard recipe for the same file in GNU Make (latest)?
Suppose I need to perform some task before a specific file type is ready to be created, but then I would like to run the generic rule:
foo.bar:
   # do something to prepare to make foo.bar

%.bar:
   # generate the `.bar` filetype

How do I evaluate the wild card recipe to generate foo.bar, having defined foo.bar for some specific prep work?

You can't.  A given target in a makefile can have only one rule and make will never try to build the same target more than one time.
What you can do is put the "shared" recipe into a variable, then use that variable in both places:
GEN_BAR = # generate the bar file type

foo.bar:
        # do something to prepare to make foo.bar
        $(GEN_BAR)

%.bar:
        $(GEN_BAR)


Actually, you can achieve this using a dependency -- create a default prep dependency that does nothing, and then a specific foo.bar.prep which will override the pattern rule:
%.bar.prep:
    @echo "no prep to be done for $*.bar"

foo.bar.prep:
    @echo "do something to prepare to make foo.bar"
    @touch $@

%.bar: %.bar.prep
    @echo "generate the '.bar' filetype"
    @touch $@

gives:
> make blah.bar
no prep to be done for blah.bar
generate the '.bar' filetype

> make blah.bar
make-3.81: `blah.bar' is up to date.

> make foo.bar
do something to prepare to make foo.bar
generate the '.bar' filetype

> make foo.bar
make-3.81: `foo.bar' is up to date.


